# ,Qué significa el comando num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);

Tags: java, android, app

Básicamente estoy haciendo un tutorial para una app de una calculadora (como todos) con android studio.

Luego de crear el diseño en Mainactivity.xml, con un EditText llamado num2 hemos escrito este código en el Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


   EditText num1, num2;
   Button suma, resta, mult, divi;
   TextView resultado;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     **num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);**
       num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2);
  }
}
```

¿Qué significa este código? ¿Qué le estoy diciendo al programa?

Comment: Hola @saeta hace cuanto tiempo iniciaste con Android y de donde has estudiado? Saludos.

Comment: Hola comenzé con Android hace 5 días, terminé ayer mi primer ejercicio: la calculadora básica

Answer (score 2):

Significa que debes tener en el layout de MainActivity un EditText con un atributo **id="num1"** Ahora el

```
num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);
```

Significa que estas asociando que el atributo **num1** es ese EditText que esta en el layout.

```
(EditText)//Estoy se le llama casting, para forzar a que lo que me envia el findViewById(R.id.num1) sea un Objecto de tipo EditText
```

Answer (score 1):

"Descifrando" el código:

```
num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);
```

---

`num1` : es una variable de tipo EditText.

---

`findViewById()` : es usado para buscar una vista determinada por su id dentro de un layout especifico. En este caso dentro del layout cargado a travez del método: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

En pocas palabras, buscamos la vista con id `num1` que se encuentra dentro del layout `activity_main.xml`.

---

`(EditText)` :  Es un `casting` para indicar que el tipo de vista a buscar es de tipo `EditText`.

---

**En resumen:**

Busca la referencia de un elemento con id `num1` que es de tipo `EditText` dentro del layout contenedor (`activity_main.xml`. ) y la almacena en la variable `num1`.

Answer (score 1):

Los que estas haciendo es inicializando tus elementos que tienes en tu XML por ejemplo

```
EditText num1, num2; //ESTAS CREANDO UNA VARIABLE DE TIPO EDITTEX
```

Despues es en el onCreat donde inicializas tus elementos ejemplo

```
num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);
//LE ESTAS DICIENDO EN LA VARIABLE DE ARRIVA VAS A TOMAR LOS VALORES QUE TENGA TU EDITTEXT QUE TIENES EN TU XML R = RECURSOS ID = ID QUE TIENE TU ELEMENTO EN EL XML Y AL FINAL COLOCAS EL NOMBRE DEL ID
```

Pero las estas declarando de manera global.

Answer (score 0):

Significa que a la variable num1 le asignas el elemento que tiene el id num1 el cuál se ubica en el la parte xml. 
En este caso estás haciendo cast para que puedas acceder a los métodos del editText.